# Append a radio button in place of Hidden checkbox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide a checkbox and inplace of that want to show a radio button..
Here you can see in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KGRvz/

But it appending in a different way.. somebody help me please

Comment: What do you mean by "appending in a different way"?

Comment: @karim79 that is appending a big space also... :-(

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because you are prepending radios to a `<tr>`. They should be placed into a cell. So I changed this:

```
$(this).parents('TR').prepend("<input type='radio'>");
```

to this:

```
$(this).parents('td').prepend("<input type='radio'>");
```

and it seems to be fine.

[**Your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KGRvz/1/)

EDIT:

Is the extra space because of the `margin-left` style you have set on the table? Try removing it.

```
<table summary="Please select your favourite cricketer?"  style="margin-left: 1em;">
```

Comment: My Requirement is radio button should come in place of Hidden Checkbox

Comment: Ok close... the <div></div>s are causeing the problem now. And the margin style needs applied too. update to your update: http://jsfiddle.net/KGRvz/2/